# How do I make my navbar expand/extend the entire page?

Tags: css, wordpress, navbar

I have purchased the following wordpress theme: http://themeforest.net/item/healthpress-health-and-medical-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/3138064

I need to make the navbar extend along the entire width of page, can someone help? Here's an image to show what i'm trying to do and Here's the CSS code for the navbar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLdsF.jpg

```
#header .main-nav { 
                    height: 21px; 
                    width: 100%; 
                    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
                    margin-top: 90px;
                    background-color:#46a1b4; 
                    background-clip: padding-box; 
                    -moz-background-clip: padding-box; 
                    -webkit-background-clip: padding; 
                    border-radius: 3px; 
                    -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
                    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;  
                    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255,.1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
                    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
                    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); /* FF3.6 */
                    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); /* IE10 */
                    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); /* Opera 11.10+ */
                    background-image:         linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
.ie7 #header .main-nav{ z-index:9600; }
.page-template-template-home-with-sidebar-php #header .main-nav,
.page-template-template-home-php #header .main-nav{ background-clip: padding-box; -moz-background-clip: padding-box; -webkit-background-clip: padding; position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px; -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px; }
#header .main-nav > ul { float: left; }
.ie7 #header .main-nav > ul { z-index:9700; }
#header .main-nav > ul > li { float: left; border-right: 1px solid #54aec2; position: relative; }
#header .main-nav > ul > li:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px; }
#header .main-nav > ul > li:last-child { border: none; }
#header .main-nav ul li a { display: inline-block; padding: 0px 20px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 41px; text-align: center; color: #fff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #20606d; }
#header .main-nav ul li:hover { background-color: #377f8f; background-clip: padding-box; -moz-background-clip: padding-box; }
#header .main-nav ul li ul { display: none; width: 220px; padding: 12px 0px; background-color: #377f8f; position: absolute; top: 41px; left: 0px; z-index: 8899; border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; }
.ie7 #header .main-nav ul li ul{ z-index:9800; }
#header .main-nav ul li ul li { width: 196px; height: 34px; padding: 0px 12px; position: relative; }
#header .main-nav ul li ul li a { display: inline-block; line-height: 34px; padding: 0px 9px;  border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; }
#header .main-nav ul li ul li:hover { background-color: #2c6774; }
#header .main-nav ul li ul li ul { top: -12px; left: 220px; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; }
.ie7 #header .main-nav ul li ul li ul { z-index:9900; }
#header .main-nav .responsive-nav { display: none; width: 100%; margin:10px auto 0px; padding:5px; border:1px solid #CCC; }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have tried changing margins, positions, width to percentages higher than %100 and to their equivalent in pixels, tried adding paddings which did increased only right part of the navbar, while the left side stayed untouched or unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
margin: 0px auto;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried doing this but it did not work, could it possibly be because there's another value over-riding it or something?

Answer (score 0):

The width of the nav bar is set to be 100%, but it is contained within the header tag which has a width of 980px. The only solution via CSS overrides would be to change the width of the header tag to be 100%, which would impact the layout of the entire top portion of your website.

I recommend putting your overrides in a child theme.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes